# Do adaptive radar receivers stack?

Tags: nebulous-fleet-command

In Nebulous: Fleet Command, can you apply multiple Adaptive Radar Receiver modules to the same ship? How much does it impact the sensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

**They stack** and you can see the results in the right hand side of the ship builder, in the sensor section.

```
v0.3.0.57 numbers:
1 ARR: +25% sensitivity, -0.7 dB, +5% position error, +2.5% velocity error.
2 ARR: +48% sensitivity, -1.35 dB, +9.6% position error, +4.8% velocity error.
4 ARR: +78% sensitivity, -2.19 dB, +15.6% position error, +7.8% velocity error.
```

So, as with most things in this game, there's diminishing returns. I find it really hard to say how effective it is in actual gameplay without doing some careful 1 on 1 tests with a friend, but them's the numbers. You can offset the error by putting in a track correlator. One correlator more than offsets the error caused by 4 ARRs.

Note also: this doesn't change the *range* of any radar, only its sensitivity, which is to say, its odds of picking up weaker signals (stealthier ships).